# Trying to reuse dplyr code block in custom function; what am I missing?

Tags: r, dplyr

Hadley says, "You should consider writing a function whenever you’ve copied and pasted a block of code more than twice"--I write this chain in dplyr often:

```
df %>%
  group_by(col) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(percent = round((n / sum(n)) * 100, 2) %>%
  arrange(desc(n))
```

I'd like to create a function that does this with two arguments: the data frame and the variable or column name.  This is what I am trying now:

```
value_counts = function(df, col) {
  group_by_(df, col) %>%
  summarise_(n = n()) %>%
  mutate_(percent = round((n / sum(n)) * 100, 2)) %>%
  arrange(desc(n))
}
```

It doesn't work and I've tried some of the other recommendations on this site but I don't quite understand how they work, e.g.:

```
value_counts = function(df, col) {
  group_by_(df, .dots = col) %>%
  summarise_(n = n()) %>%
  mutate_(percent = round((n / sum(n)) * 100, 2)) %>%
  arrange(desc(n))
}
```

I really want to write a function that uses the pipes and relies on dplyr.  I could continue writing the code that works over and over again, but I'd like to start writing useful functions in R to save time.

I'm a big fan of geom_text() and like having the info from dplyr in a data frame quick and easily so I can get lots of graphs made quickly!

Any resources I should read or links to follow would be useful.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@jenesaisquoi's answer is great, but whenever I write `dplyr`-y functions, I try to write them in a similar style as in that package. I would like to have a SE and NSE pair of functions, where you can use bare variable names.

A few things to note.

- I got rid of the pipes (`%>%`) making them slightly faster and easier to debug. Pipes are super convenient in interactive use, but I tend to avoid them while programming functions.
- I used `::` everywhere a package specific function is used. This means you now don't need to have `dplyr` loaded to use the function.
- I saw no reason to limit use to only one column, so made a `...` argument instead, that accept grouping by as many columns as needed.
- See `vignette(NSE)` for more details on the use of the `lazyeval` package, and the way `dplyr` deals with `...` and `.dots`.

#### Functions

```
value_counts <- function(df, ...) {
  value_counts_(df, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...))
}

value_counts_ <- function(df, ..., .dots) {
  dots <- lazyeval::all_dots(.dots, ..., all_named = TRUE)
  df <- dplyr::group_by_(df, .dots = dots)
  df <- dplyr::summarise(df, n = n())
  df <- dplyr::mutate(df, percent = round(n / sum(n) * 100, 2))
  df <- dplyr::arrange(df, desc(n))
  return(df)
}
```

#### Examples

```
value_counts(mtcars, cyl)
value_counts(mtcars, cyl, vs)

value_counts_(mtcars, ~cyl)
value_counts_(mtcars, ~cyl, ~vs)
value_counts_(mtcars, .dots = list(~cyl, ~vs))
```

And you can easily pipe them together with other `dplyr` verbs:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  filter(cyl != 4) %>%
  value_counts()
```

Comment: Your function doesn't give the same result for `value_counts(iris, "Species")`. Removing the first `.dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)` and some of the other `.dots` makes it return the same.

Comment: Use value_counts(iris, Species) instead. Or use value_counts_(iris, "Species")

Comment: Thank you @Axeman !!  I was trying to write a function that was `dplyr`-y and really wanted the second argument to accept more columns if needed--that was going to be something I tried to work out after solving this issue first, so thank you for including it in your answer.  I will definitely read the vignette you recommended so I can get a better handle of the `...` and `dots`.  This is a great starting point for custom functions--again thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Only replace the NSE functions with their standard equivalents when you are passing a column name as a string to them.  In your case, that is only in the `group_by_` function where `col` is a variable, assuming you want to call your function like `value_counts(df, "some_column")`.  The intermediaries, `n` and `percent` aren't reliant on the variable, so don't need to be changed at all.

```
value_counts <- function(df, col) {
  group_by_(df, col) %>%
    summarise(n = n()) %>%
    mutate(percent = round(n / sum(n) * 100, 2)) %>%
    arrange(desc(n))
}
value_counts(iris, "Species")
```

Comment: Thank you @jenesaisquoi this definitely solves my issue.  I should have said that I wanted to pass the second argument without quotes; my bad.  But I appreciate your answer and it works.